# Can we have two domains in the App domain for facebook apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created an sample application for development and I've created another sample application with all the same properties except domain, since all the return_urls should be based on the domain. I'm using One version at my localhost and using other version in another test domain.

So whenever i copy all the code to my test domain, i need to change the app key , secret and return url etc..

What i need to know is whether its possible to add two or more domains for a single app and only change the return url **without** changing the app key, secret etc..??

**Update:**

Sorry i intended to say without changing app key, secret.. That was a typo mistake that changed the whole context of the question.

Comment: @rudolf_franek I think what Vijay is asking is how can he set it up so that he can use the same registered APP on his localhost AND on his domain without it complaining about the URL not being authorised.

Comment: Sorry @udolf_franek  , that was a typo mistake, i just want to add two domains and keep all the other settings intact and just want to know whether that will work from two different domains?

Comment: But this won't allow for full testing (logging in / authorisation) on two domains, it will just allow offline access.

Comment: That because for the same app(i.e key and secret) you have given the offline access , that means you never logged out and the cookie never gets deleted.. But i dont want to have offline access

Comment: I see - sorry. I can only guess you may use two domains as subdomains of one domain you provide in your facebook app settings.

Comment: Whenever we add a domain , the subdomains are automatically added . There is no need to specify individually. But my need is different. If its not possible , then what i had done earlier is the way to go.. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can now create a [Test App](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps) as a "child" app of your main app.

> Similar to Test Users, Test Apps let you quickly create Facebook App IDs for use during the development, testing, staging or QA phases of the app development lifecycle.
>
> Test Apps are like regular apps in that they have their own App ID and independent settings, but they offer a number of advantages for use during pre-production

A test app has its own URL and Domain, independent of the parent app.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. This has already been answered here: [Allowing multiple domains for 1 Facebook App (like Tumblr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511321/allowing-multiple-domains-for-1-facebook-app-like-tumblr)

You will need to set up a new facebook app for each distinct domain you create. Ideally you should have a configuration file for each domain in which you can store the app id/secret thereby preventing the need to edit it with each deploy.

Answer (score -1):

Below steps help me to solve same problem.

1. Go to developers.facebook.com.
2. Click on your application and edit the settings.:
3. Add domains to that in the following form: example.com, example.org, subdomain.example.com (no http).
4. Save.