# Cross domain Facebook apps best practice

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Heads up**, I know there have been a number of questions on this topic before, this is not a duplicate.

Facebook officially offers limited cross domain functionality at present, allowing for subdomains, and different domains sharing the same base URL. (See this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/09/30/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/)) Aside from these, Facebook state they do not offer cross domain functionality.

However, this isn't technically true, as they actually do... to an extent. It is possible to specify an entirely different URL in the Mobile URL, Canvas URL, or Page Tab URL fields, providing full cross-domain functionality.

**Use case:** there are probably a few, but in my case I'm building a Shopify app, where the thank-you page of the checkout is on `checkout.shopify.com`, while the main site is on `mydomain.com`.

There appears to be very limited discussion on this. The two resources I've managed to find are:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20358123/3653398
- [The Hull.io documentation](http://hull.io/help/social-features/integrating_with_fb_sdk/#listening-to-facebook-events-and-funneling-them-through-hull) (they encourage using an external domain for the SDK)

The fact that there is no official documentation on this worries me, it doesn't feel like "officially supported functionality", even if it does appear to work flawlessly.

Has anyone looked into this before?

Comment: No it is not officially supported. And if you submit for review any platform you added will be reviewed so do not fill in stuff just to enable cross domain stuff

Comment: What about if we use just the web platform with the mobile URL? That's still part of the website platform. Unfortunately we need to have this enabled for approval - they need to be able to verify an Open Graph story dependent on the cross domain functionality.

Comment: There is no any best practice since all practices are not officially supported, but you can set eg. page tab or mobile web.