# How to get magento multistore work with facebook app

Tags: magento, facebook-graph-api

I sat up facebook connect extension on my magento store, which allows customer to login to the store with their facebook account. After filling api key, api secret in magento and config site url in facebook apps, the extension worked perfectly. However, if I switch to another store (with another domain), it won't work anymore. Is there a way to have magento connect to facebook without matching site url?

Here is the extension I got from: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/facebook-connect-magento-extension/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully aware of how that Magento app works internally, however what I would say is that Facebook strictly speaking, does not allow apps to work across multiple different URLs. You can add multiple **subdomains**, however.

There is also some unsupported functionality allowing you to run apps across different domains details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336718/cross-domain-facebook-apps-best-practice), though it's worth remembering, this is unsupported.

The [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/register-facebook-application) have some more info on "App Domains", and how they should be configured.