# Same Facebook comments plugin for different URLs

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

Lets assume you have 2 website versions that share single database: a mobile version and a desktop version of your main website. Their URLs differ significantly.

Is it possible to implement the same Facebook plugin (using one the same Facebook app) on each of them? What I need to achieve is to show same comments below same articles no matter that their URLs differ.

Sample URLs for one article:

1) On the desktop version: https://www.somesite.com/somepath/article1
2) On the mobile version: https://m.somesite.com/differentpath/article1

They show the same content but totally differ as URL. So they should include the same comments. Is that doable with a single Facebook app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowing multiple domains for 1 Facebook App (like Tumblr)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511321/allowing-multiple-domains-for-1-facebook-app-like-tumblr)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible.

All you have to do is set the `og:url` meta tag for both “versions” of an article (desktop and mobile) to the same URL – so decide on one as the “main” URL, and use that.

(And make sure that the FB scraper does not automatically redirected to the other one, if you have any such thing in place.)

Comment: I didn't manage to do this so far. Should I register another app?

Comment: Not necessarily, I think it should work fine without one. Make sure to use the debug tool to check your implementation, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug