# Need to add multiple domains in a single Facebook Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to add multiple domains in my Facebook App but not succeeded as yet,

I have researched a lot and got that Facebook keeps changing its settings time to time , adding multiple domains was not possible initially but then they made it possible then again it was made unavailable.

But got no update if it can be done now,

Anyhow, I tried to put multiple domains but got error

```
 App domains must match the domain of the Secure Canvas URL, Mobile Site
 URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Please correct 
 these domains: www.chair.com, www.table.com
```

what does this error mean? and how to resolve it?

And is it possible to attach multiple domains with a single app?

**Example of domains:**

www.table.com

www.chair.com

www.desk.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible, unless only the extension or subdomain is different.

e.g.

The following is possible:

`table.com` and `table.co.uk` and `sub.table.com`

The following is not:

`table.com` and `chair.com`

Comment: Ohkkay, Can we have any reference to any official document on this?I would really appreciate if you could provide.

Comment: @HappyDev https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security Also edit: subdomains should be allowed also.